# Publish a subset of an Eclipse Project to github

Tags: eclipse, github

I have a large project defined on my localhost that has 80525 files. Many of the files are not related to code, for example: template files, caching files, images, etc.

The only files I am working on are in /var/www/vhosts/sitename.com/httpdocs/support/modules/server

When I right click the files I want to commit to github I get a dailog that says:
"Calculating changes in selected repositories" and then it computes changes in the repository that takes about 20 minutes (obviously going through 80525 files takes a while).

In order to reduce Eclipse processing I have excluded all of the project files except the ones I am working on.

What I am trying to find out is how to publish only a subset of files to Github using Eclipse. Ideally I still want my project to have access to all the files because I reference them a lot, but when I commit I only want Eclipse to "see" certain directories and subdirectories.

One way of doing this would have been to create two projects, one with my main files, and another with just the files I am working on. The problem I find is when you define two projects in Eclipse, and the second project has references subdirectories from the 1st project, Eclipse gives an error.

My question is what would be the correct way to get Eclipse to only commit the files from the subdirectory of the folder that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use .gitignore, or right click file / Team / Ignore on the files in question.